# inequality with radicals

Tags: inequality

Let $y\ge x\ge 1$. What is the best constant $k$ for which the following inequality holds
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{x^2+y^2+xy}+2\sqrt{y^2+y+1}+3\sqrt{x^2+x+1}\le k(1+x+y)?
\end{equation*}
It is very easy to prove that $k\le 4$ while certainly $k\ge 2\sqrt{3}$ since this is achieved when $x=y=1$.

I suspect that $k=2\sqrt{3}$ but I cannot prove it. Any ideas would be appreciated.